# No longer able to create or modify folder/file in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-20.04, wps-spreadsheet

I was making changes to an Excel file(.xlsx) in WPS in my Windows 10 partition, and tried saving it when I got the following dialog box that my file had suddenly changed to read-only mode, which is strange as earlier I could make changes to it.

I was given as Save as option in the dialog box and on clicking it I got the following:

Cannot save to the directory:
[image: Cannot save to directory error]

On researching for solutions I found out that it is possible that my drive has a file-system error?
[Reference Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963944/you-are-trying-to-save-the-file-on-a-read-only-disk-when-trying-to-save-a-file)

I tried to run `smartmontools` but was unable to understand anything from it.

How can I fix this problem so I can once again create folders and files in my Windows partition?

Comment: smart tools are for checking a whole hard drive/ssd's "stats." You would want a filesystem check like one of the fsck family, if the drive is ntfs then maybe ntfsfix? Check the syslog (maybe `dmesg) and see if the fs was automatically remounted read-only, that often happens when errors are detected.

Comment: While working on an Office file, a *lock* file is created, preventing others from trying to make simultaneous changes. That file is normally deleted when the app closes, but if it's been left in that folder, it prevents saving the file there. Delete the lock file.  Open that folder in a file manager and confirm that you *do* have write permission by creating an empty file.